# Kafka Connect Transformation: Extract a Long value from json field and insert as key

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, transform, apache-kafka-connect

I have the following json on a topic that the JDBC connector publishes to

```
{"APP_SETTING_ID":9,"APP_SETTING_NAME":"my_name","SETTING_KEY":"my_setting_key"}
```

Here's my connector file

```
name=data.app_setting
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
poll.interval.ms=500
tasks.max=4
mode=timestamp
query=SELECT APP_SETTING_ID, APP_SETTING_NAME, SETTING_KEY,FROM MY_TABLE with (nolock)
timestamp.column.name=LAST_MOD_DATE
topic.prefix=data.app_setting

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

transforms=InsertKey
transforms.InsertKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.InsertKey.fields=APP_SETTING_ID
```

This does add a key but its also a json format like

```
{"APP_SETTING_ID":9}
```

While I just want 9 to be the key instead of the map. In the database it's stored as a Long value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ValueToKey` takes a list of fields within the value, and returns a mapping of those fields to their values.

I think you need a second transform to extract only a single one of those fields.

```
transforms=ReplaceKey,ExtractKey

# Replaces the key with fields in the value. Creates a map for all listed fields
transforms.ReplaceKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.ReplaceKey.fields=APP_SETTING_ID

# Extracts a specfic field from the key, assuming it's a map/struct type
transforms.ExtractKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.ExtractKey.field=APP_SETTING_ID
```

Comment: if possible, could you please also explain what's happening here. Specifically in the ExtractField$Key part

Comment: The dollar sign is just Java class syntax for accessing an inner class

Comment: So are you extractin the key? By intuition it should be the value 9 no? Also, what should the key.converter be in this case. Currently its org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter even though its not JSON now. It still works.Just not sure what the converter is doing

Comment: Yes, it gets 9 for your example. If your data isn't JSON, then the converter would fail in serialization. A plain string or integer is still valid JSON, though

Comment: One last question :) - I tried org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.LongConverter but my kafka doesnt recognize it. I am using kafka 1.0 and Confluent 3.0 Is it something that needs to be installed or does it come with a different version number

Comment: That is only available starting with Kafka 2.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6913 . Other than that, It would be recommended to use Confluent 4.x, which includes Kafka 1.x libraries